# css border property {1,4} meaning?

Tags: css, border

while looking at the border property w3c specs, trying to determine what {1,4} means? is it width? I believe width can't be restricted between 1-4, so what is it?

```
[ thin | medium | thick | <length> ]{1,4} | inherit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you can set there between 1 and 4 values.

## Examples

```
border: 1px              = border: 1px 1px         = border: 1px 1px 1px      = border: 1px 1px 1px 1px
border: 1px 2px          = border: 1px 2px 1px     = border: 1px 2px 1px 2px
border: 1px 2px 3px      = border: 1px 2px 3px 2px
border: 1px 2px 3px 4px

// values behind "=" are equivalent, you can choose what is better for you.
```

## Values order

Order of values is: `top - right - bottom - left`

## General Info

- When you set only one value, it means: "set this border to all sides"
- When you set two values, the first one is `border-top` and `bottom`, the second one is for `border-left` and `right`.
- When you set three values, the first one is for top, the second one for `right` and `left`, the third one for `bottom`.
- When you set all values, it´s `top-right-bottom-left`.

Comment: This notation, and other notations used in the formal syntax definitions, is explained at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/about.html#property-defs

Answer (score 2):

I only refers to syntax. From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width):

> Formal syntax: {1,4}
>
> ```
> border-width: width                    /* One-value syntax   */
> border-width: horizontal vertical      /* Two-value syntax   */
> border-width: top horizontal bottom    /* Three-value syntax */
> border-width: top right bottom left    /* Four-value syntax  */
> ```

So you can define `border-width` using 1, 2, 3, or 4 values. If you use:

1. (One value) It applies to all sides.
2. (Two values) The first value is applied to the horizontal (i.e. top and bottom), and the second to the vertical (i.e. left and right)

...and so on.

A lot of CSS properties inherit a similar pattern, such as the shorcut for `padding`, `margin`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify one border property for the entire element or four separate borders for left, right, top and bottom of the element.

```
p { border: solid red }

p {
  border-top: solid red;
  border-right: solid red;
  border-bottom: solid red;
  border-left: solid red
}
```

Another example is given in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border-style) of `border-style` property:

```
#xy34 { border-style: solid dotted }
```

*In the above example, the horizontal borders will be 'solid' and the vertical borders will be 'dotted'.*

Answer (score 0):

{1-4} means that you can specify 1, 2, 3 or 4 values or the property.

The four values for each radii are given in the order top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left. If bottom-left is omitted it is the same as top-right. If bottom-right is omitted it is the same as top-left. If top-right is omitted it is the same as top-left.